# How to inject parameters in enum constructor using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    ONE (new MyClass()),
    TWO (new MyClass());

    private final MyClass instance;

    private SomeEnum(MyClass instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
}
```

How can I pass MyClass instance to the enum constructor from Spring context? Is it even possible?

I need it because I pass some parameters from config (.properties file) into MyClass instance while I create it. Now I'm doing it in xml-file with beans, maybe there is another way?

Comment: I think you can instead declare MyClass instances as beans in the container and transform SomeEnum to [qualifier](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers). Generally it's not a good idea to mix Java singletons with Spring singleton beans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this.

In this [official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) on Enum Types, it states

> Note: The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or
>   private access. It automatically creates the constants that are
>   defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum
>   constructor yourself.

Since an Enum is supposed to be a constant set of constants, it doesn't make sense to be able to create new ones, so the constructors are not available, even through reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Even when we talk in context of Spring , i think that is also not possible.

You cannot instantiate enums because they have a static nature. So I think that Spring IoC can't create enums as well.

please have a look at [Spring IoC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) chapter.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do however, is leverage MyClass within the enum to encapsulate some 'constant' behaviour.  You can take this as far as you like (***not that it's necessarily a great idea...***) for example you might use some static factory class to load property values based on those constant names passed in.

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    ONE ("propname1"),
    TWO ("propname2");

    private final MyClass instance;

    private SomeEnum(String str) {
        this.instance = MyClassFactory.newInstance(str);
    }

    public Object doSomething(int value) {
        return instance.doSomething(value);
    }
}
```